# Adding vertices to graph using ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to add create two ArrayList of vertices (setA, setB) which will store the stores for comparing  them late how ever I am unable to add vertices to the arraylist.

here is the code

```
import java.util.*;


public class BipartiteGraph<Vertex> {

    private String strName;
    ArrayList<Vertex>[] vertexList;

    public BipartiteGraph(){

        vertexList = new ArrayList[2];
        vertexList[0] = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        vertexList[1] = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        Scanner vertexInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int vertex;
        vertex = vertexInput.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            vertexList[0].add(vertexInput.nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

Also if someone could guide me if I am in the right direction.

Comment: You are trying to add an `int` to an `ArrayList` that contains `Vertex`es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add `int` variable into the container of `Vertex` objects. Assuming, that your `Vertex` has a constructor accepting `int` you should rather use:

```
vertexList[0].add(new Vertex(vertexInput.nextInt()));
```

Comment: how can I instantiate the vertex here?

Comment: simply define the constructor accepting `int`, like: public Vertex(int v){ .... }`